# Calculate time difference in Swift 4

Tags: swift

If I have two variables, "10:30" and another one "1:20", is there a way to to get the time difference between them of "2 hr and 50 min"?? I tried this below

```
func calcTime(time1: String,time2: String) -> String {
    let time12 = (String(format: "%02d", time1))
    let time22 = (String(format: "%02d", time2))

    let time10 = time12.prefix(2)
    let time20 = time22.prefix(2)

    print("hours: \(time12)")
    print("minutes: \(time22)")

    let time11 = time1.suffix(2)
    let time21 = time2.suffix(2)

    var hours = 12 - Int(time10)! + Int(time20)!
    var minutes = Int(time11)! + Int(time21)!

    if minutes > 60 {
        hours += 1
        minutes -= 60
    }

    let newHours = (String(format: "%02d", hours))
    let newMin = (String(format: "%02d", minutes))

   return "\(newHours)hrs. \(newMin)min."
}
```

It's not really working the way I want it to.

Comment: What I would do is convert them to TimeInterval then subtract the from another then convert the difference to your string format.

Comment: Actually the difference is 2 hr and 50 min.  And `1:20` is obviously PM, but how do you distinguish AM / PM? And I don't understand the first `String(format` lines. What are they supposed to do if the argument is a string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, your math is wrong. 10:30 -> 1:20 is actually 2 hr 50 min. Second, you need to specify AM or PM, or use a 24-hour (military-style) clock. Finally, the solution is to use `DateFormatter` to convert the strings into `Date` values and use those to get the time difference, which you can then convert into hours/minutes.

```
    let time1 = "10:30AM"
    let time2 = "1:20PM"

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mma"

    let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1)!
    let date2 = formatter.date(from: time2)!

    let elapsedTime = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)

    // convert from seconds to hours, rounding down to the nearest hour
    let hours = floor(elapsedTime / 60 / 60)

    // we have to subtract the number of seconds in hours from minutes to get
    // the remaining minutes, rounding down to the nearest minute (in case you
    // want to get seconds down the road)
    let minutes = floor((elapsedTime - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60)

    print("\(Int(hours)) hr and \(Int(minutes)) min")
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. I figured out a way yesterday, but it took me 120 lines of code. This is much simpler and isn't as big.

Comment: How to get seconds also, I want to show like mm:ss.

Comment: let seconds = floor((elapsedTime - (minutes * 60)))

Comment: I try this but this line   let date1 = formatter.date(from: time1)!  through nil value exception

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at some of your code and see what it produces strange results:

```
let time12 = (String(format: "%02d", time1))
```

This line makes no sense, the format `%02d` is saying the value to be formatted (converted to a `String` representation) is an integer and the conversion should be 2 digits wide with a leading zero. However your argument, `time1` is a `String` value, not an integer.

Unfortunately Swift doesn't point this mistake out to you, rather it just bites. Due to the way `String(format:...)` works – it takes a variable number of arguments – Swift usual type-checking is abandoned and what what you are getting back is a decimal representation of (possibly part of) the machine address of `time1`. Run your code multiple times in the Playground and you'll get different answers!

So be *very* careful when using `String(format:...)`.

Its unclear here what you are attempting to do with the above line, you have a `String` value and wish to extract two integer values from it, so why start by producing a `String` (`let time12 = String(...time1...)`)?

```
let time10 = time12.prefix(2)
let time11 = time1.suffix(2)
```

Skipping mixing up which variable (`time12`, `time1`) contains your `String` here you are assuming the string is exactly of the format ; but one of your test strings is `"1:20"`, so even if these statements referred to the correct variables you would end up with `"1:"` and `"20"` in this case.

What you can do to split your strings into the two parts is to use `String`'s `split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)` function, check the documentation for its full description. Here you can write:

```
let time1parts = time1.split(separator: ":", omittingEmptySubsequences:false)
let time2parts = time2.split(separator: ":", omittingEmptySubsequences:false)

print("\(time1) -> \(time1parts)")
print("\(time2) -> \(time2parts)")
```

For your two test strings this will output:

```
10:30 -> ["10", "30"]
1:20 -> ["1", "20"]
```

Now you should check that each array (`time1parts`, `time2parts`) has exactly two elements, that is left as an exercise.

Having done that you can convert the elements to unsigned integers (just in case someone types a minus sign). E.g:

```
let hours1 = UInt(time1parts[0])
let minutes1 = UInt(time1parts[1])

print("\(String(describing: hours1)) | \(String(describing: minutes1))")
```

This outputs:

```
Optional(10) | Optional(30)
```

Now you need to check the optional (`Uint?`) values are not `nil`, that each value is in the correct range (e.g. 0 to 59 for minutes, the `Range` type and it's method `contains()` might help you here) and do your math.

Note: you do have a problem in that you are assuming `1:20` is PM, you need to address this your your math will never be correct. Maybe use the 24 hour clock (`13:20`)?

If you get stuck further along ask a new question showing the code you have developed and explain your problem, someone will undoubtedly help you along.